# O365 Graph, strange error on message download on some mailboxes, not all

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

i have hundreds of users using my wpf app to download O365 messages (using c# Graph SDK), since some weeks small portions are having error on 1 or more mailboxes when downloading message.

The error returned by Graph sdk in c#:
ErrorInternalServerError Message: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed. ClientRequestId: 54e9e307-1a60-4f78-9f8f-5def1c6fb5b5

As i can't reproduce the problem on my side, it is very hard to find the problem, here some information:

- A user can have 20 mailboxes and only 1 or 3 are no more working
- The problem is only on downloading messages, the OAuth connection is working fine, i can get the list of folders, the number of messages in the folder,...
- When the user deletes and re-create the email box in O365 it will work again
- If the user connects with IMAP instead of Graph it works fine!

Here the code i use to download MIME message (which works fine since many months):

```
var _request = m_graphClient.Users[m_Account.Server_EmailAddress].Messages[pMessageID].Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
_request.RequestUri = new Uri(_request.RequestUri.OriginalString + "/$value");
var _response = await m_graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(_request);
```

With same result i tried also:

```
var _responseStream = await m_graphClient.Users[m_Account.Server_EmailAddress].Messages[pMessageID].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

The problem sounds like there is an O365 mailbox update rolling, i have more and more users having this problem suddenly.

I hope you can guide me to find the problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) How big are these messages or do they contain bigger attachments/recipients?

Comment: (2) To isolate the issue, get the ids of the messages and check the same api call in POSTMAN/Graph Explorer and see if it works or not.

Comment: (3) No need to compare two protocols/APIs, as both are not the same nor use the same architecture/standards

Comment: (4) How a user can have 20 mailboxes? Sorry i am confused, please explain.

Comment: (5) check the status of these mailboxes in office 365 portal or microsoft support to see if there are any upgrades happening on these mailboxes

Comment: (6)Get the necessary graph responses (detailed error, requestid, timestamp) for the analysis and do share it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the attachments are under the 3mb (and some emails don't have  attachment).
When i wrote a user can have 20 mailboxes, i mean the user can manage 20 mailboxes in his company and only 1 or 2 have the problem.
The problem to test with Postman is i need credential to connect the mailbox with problem, i can't, it is on user(customer) side...
All customers told me that nothing has changed on their side, i can't check myself on their O365 portal.

Comment: How can i get the detailed error from the c# graph sdk? The only error on the TRY is:
ErrorInternalServerError Message: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed. ClientRequestId: 54e9e307-1a60-4f78-9f8f-5def1c6fb5b5

Thank you.

Comment: ok i hear you... in such scenario, they can perform the call in Graph explorer or postman.. also they can submit the request at the portal as well

Comment: I tried to find the problem from customer computer, with no luck, here the typical situation:
- Shared mailbox is working fine, then suddenly my app can't download the message (yesterday it was working, not today).
- I connect to customer computer, launch Graph explorer from browser, log with customer credential and run the command to get message with id, it is working fine.

So i suspect an update in O365 mailbox like authorization, our app use these consents:
- Mail.Send.Shared
- Mail.ReadWrite.Shared
- IMAP. AcceessAsUser.All
- SMTP.Send
- User.Read

Any idea?

Comment: If its working with graph explorer then you can take API out of the picture here. Sounds like issue with the underlying service from O365 or your customer infra. Ask them to open a support ticket with Microsoft to see if they can help them to isolate and fix the issue.

Comment: Do you know the best way to contact Microsoft O365 team for this type of problem? (which team to contact exactly)

Comment: Once you create a ticket using the M365 portal, i think they will internally engage the right teams.